# How to make an AutoMapper naming convention to ignore underscores

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-13

I'm using AutoMapper to map POCO's in the usual way. But I have a common scenario where I want to map a class like:

```
class MyClassSrc
{
  public int my_property {get; set;}
}
```

```
class MyClassDest
{
  public int MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

But I think I need more flexibility than what's offered by:

```
cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
```

because the destination object *may or may not* cleanly be called `MyProperty`. For instance, I may generally want that format, but there might be another case where I want it to be `Acronym_XYZ` or `_3D_Game`, where I leave in the underscore to be more readable, or because a .net identifier can't start with a number.

I also always want case insensitive mapping.

Will the built in naming conventions simply *ignore* all underscores, and remain case sensitive, correctly mapping `my_property` to `My_Property`, or do I need a custom convention for this?  (And if so, how do you build one that compare source and destination property names in this fuzzy sense)?

Comment: Please edit your question to include several/all example mappings you want to have between the two classes. Also show the results of these mappings when using the available naming convention like `LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention`, `PascalCaseNamingConvention` or `ExactMatchNamingConvention` and how/where they don't work.

Comment: I'd recommend to setup a bunch of unit tests to see what works out of the box and what does not.